# AS3 dynamic text algorithm

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, dynamic

Afternoon,
I have an odd algorithm. I would like to populate a string of code dynamically based on some user entry.

I have a multi-dimensional array with data in it and a multi-line input text field.

What I want is for a user to be able to enter some text
example:
00
01 - 02 - 03
comments: 12

my code would identify the numbers an treat everything else as text.
Thus, if my array is data[x][#], the # will correspond to their entry.

I would get

```
algorithm_string = data[x][0] + "\n" + data[x][1] + " - " + data[x][2] + " - " + data[x][3] + "\n" + "comments: " + data[x][12]
```

So the algorithm would construct the above, and then I could run through the code.

```
for(var x:int = 0; x < data.length; x++){
    some_object._display_text.text = algorithm_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I want to first say that relying on a user to put in the entry exactly the way you want is probably not a good idea.  They WILL make mistakes and your code WILL eventually not work as expected.  I would recommend using 5 inputs restricted to numeric input, and labeling each field with which number should go in it.

However, you can accomplish what you are trying to do above like this:

```
var parts:Array = myInput.text.split(" ");

for (var i:int=0; i<parts.length, i++){
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(parts[i]))){
        // you have a number here.
        data[x].push(parts[i]);
    } else {
        //this was not a number so ignore it
    }
}
```

Again let me state I think you should refactor how you get the numbers, but that code will grab the numbers out and put them in the 0,1,2,3,and 4 indexes of your data[x], but relies on the user perfectly inputting the text every time.

Good luck! (refactor) :)

Comment: That's a good start for identifying what is text vs insertable field.<br/>However, I am looking not to push data into my data Array, but to build what information should be pulled from it.<br/>I can create an array of text items:<br/>new_array:Array = new Array(Number, string, string, number, string, number, string, number, string);<br/><br/>
then as I go through the array, if it is a number, pull that number's value from the data[][] array?<br/><br/>
I will give this a try and let you know how it goes.